# setting variable to value within an array

Tags: php, arrays

I need to refer to the value1, value2, or value3, within an array like this one:

```
a:3:{i:0;s:4:"value1";i:1;s:5:"value2";i:2;s:4:"value3";}
```

value 1, 2, or 3 are actually ids and I need to find a way to set them equal to an `$item->ID` so that they can be saved as selected in a dropdown menu. Also the array is infinite - not necessarily `a:3` (I'm trying to create repeatable select boxes.)

basically I need to set a variable reference every third item in the array.

I would love some help on this. As you can probably tell I'm fairly new at php.

Edit: I think I've explained this badly. Basically in order to make my code work I need 
$meta to equal $item-ID Right now meta is equal to a:1:{i:0;s:3:"202";} and $item-ID is equal to 202. I can't change the value or the fact that it is seralized because its from wordpress and I'm accessing infomation already present.

```
foreach($items as $item) {
echo '<option value="'.$item->ID.'"',$meta == $item->ID ? ' selected="selected"' : '','>'.$item->display_name.'</option>';
                }
```

Comment: What is it that you've tried thus far?

Comment: In case you actually have that as an array, the output of `var_dump`/`print_r` is a bit more readable than that of `serialize` btw.

Comment: Is this your "array", serialized, or is this just a representation of an actual array? Is your problem working with this array representation or just the algorithm which elements to set? It would also help if you showed your initial array and the expected result.

Comment: This is what is in the Mysql database. probably just an algorithm problem. I don't actually need to display it yet just capture the value of the item in the places of value 1, 2 and 3 etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well if i were you i would unserialize to a normal array - then change whatever i want then re serialize

as follows:

```
$newArray = unserialize('a:3:{i:0;s:6:"value1";i:1;s:6:"value2";i:2;s:6:"value3";}');
foreach($newArray as something){} //or whatever else you want to do on the normal array.
$serializeArray = serialize ($newArray);
```

basically in my opinion working with serialized arrays is a mistake..

Comment: I can't help it. Its from the Wordpress admin page. I didn't tag it wordpress as I figured it was more of a php problem

Comment: I understand but you should still be able to manipulate it as you wish.

Comment: Thanks I'm trying. But seeing as I can't even seem to grasp arrays that's a pretty tall order ;)

Comment: I've tried: $newArray = unserialize($meta);
        foreach($newArray as $key=> $value){ 
         return  $value;} <?php var_dump($value); ?> but I get NULL

Comment: will you give me more information what exactly are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: I edited the original post as it wasn't very clear:Edit: I think I've explained this badly. Basically in order to make my code work I need $meta to equal $item-ID Right now meta is equal to a:1:{i:0;s:3:"202";} and $item-ID is equal to 202. I can't change the value or the fact that it is seralized because its from wordpress and I'm accessing infomation already present.

foreach($items as $item) {
echo '<option value="'.$item->ID.'"',$meta == $item->ID ? ' selected="selected"' : '','>'.$item->display_name.'</option>';
                }

Answer (score 0):

```
$x = unserialize($your_array);
foreach ($x as $key => &$val) {
    if ($key % 3 == 0) {
        $val = $item->ID;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a serialized array representation. But there are errors in it. the string length `s:4` or `s:5` are wrong. Although it is really hackish to fix this manually, here comes working code, I've set `s:6` as the strings have 6 chars:

```
$a = unserialize('a:3:{i:0;s:6:"value1";i:1;s:6:"value2";i:2;s:6:"value3";}');
var_dump($a);
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  [0] =>
  string(6) "value1"
  [1] =>
  string(6) "value2"
  [2] =>
  string(6) "value3"
}
```

Now you have an array. But the question is, how could you get that string? What are you doing exactly?

If you are searching for a way how to define an array in php, use this for example:

```
$array = array ('value1', 'value2', 'value3');
```

There are other ways to define arrays as well. Please [read the manual about arrays](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Comment: that is my fault. I was trying to make it easier to explain. Actually I'm trying to to reference an id in a drop-down select box and set it equal to another variable so it will save to the db. Here is what I'd eventually like to output: a:1:{i:0;s:3:"202";} basically I need to get the 202 (or whatever it is) and make it == to 202 som that it will stay selected.